# Own background on selected item on my spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors, spinner

I use PowerSpinner on my application (https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner).

My problem is that I want to have own background color on selected item. I know how to do this on a normal spinner but can't do this on PowerSpinner.

Material have a sample how to implement a custom adapter but is write on Kotlin and I have no ideea about kotlin.

How is java version for next code?

```
class MySpinnerAdapter(
powerSpinnerView: PowerSpinnerView) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MySpinnerAdapter.MySpinnerViewHolder>(),
PowerSpinnerInterface<MySpinnerItem> {}
```

Can you help me to implement to PowerSpinner my own background color?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Adapter(powerSpinnerView: PowerSpinnerView
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.IconSpinnerViewHolder>(),
    PowerSpinnerInterface<Data> {

    override var index: Int = powerSpinnerView.selectedIndex
    override val spinnerView: PowerSpinnerView = powerSpinnerView
    override var onSpinnerItemSelectedListener: OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener<Data>? = null`
    private val compoundPadding: Int = 12
    private var spinnerItems: MutableList<Data> = arrayListOf()

    init {
        this.spinnerView.compoundDrawablePadding = compoundPadding
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IconSpinnerViewHolder {
        val binding =
            ItemDefaultPowerSpinnerLibraryBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,
                false
            )
        return IconSpinnerViewHolder(binding).apply {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition.takeIf { it != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION }
                    ?: return@setOnClickListener
                notifyItemSelected(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IconSpinnerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(spinnerItems[position], spinnerView)
        
    }

    override fun setItems(itemList: List<Data>) {
        this.spinnerItems.clear()
       this.spinnerItems= itemList.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun notifyItemSelected(index: Int) {
        if (index == 0) return
        val item = spinnerItems[index]
        val oldIndex = this.index
        this.index = index
        this.spinnerView.notifyItemSelected(index, item.name)
        this.onSpinnerItemSelectedListener?.onItemSelected(
            oldIndex = oldIndex,
            oldItem = oldIndex.takeIf { it != 0 }?.let { spinnerItems[oldIndex] },
            newIndex = index,
            newItem = item
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = this.spinnerItems.size

    class IconSpinnerViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDefaultPowerSpinnerLibraryBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: Data, spinnerView: PowerSpinnerView) {
            binding.itemDefaultText.apply {
                text = item.name
                gravity = spinnerView.gravity
                setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, spinnerView.textSize)
                setTextColor(spinnerView.currentTextColor)
            }
            binding.root.setPadding(
                spinnerView.paddingLeft,
                spinnerView.paddingTop,
                spinnerView.paddingRight,
                spinnerView.paddingBottom
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your code is on kotlin. I wrote that I don't have any ideea about kotlin. "How is java version for next code?"